# Month over Year calculation/comparison

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a situation where I need to compare a month in one year to a month in a previous year. For example, I want to be able to see the MRR (monthly recurring revenue) in November 2023 and how it compares to the MRR for November 2022.

I have:

- Total Contract Value
- Contract Start Date
- Contract End Date

Currently, we are creating separate columns in excel for every month of the year and doing a relatively complicated formula to capture the MRR for each month and then we create a pivot table with that information and then two more tables that show the comparison between months of different years. So, if we're doing YOY comparisons for January 2019 through December 2023, I'll have 60 columns in excel. Needless to say, this isn't very scalable and is incredibly manual so I'm hoping Power BI will have a better solution!

**Bottom Line: If a contract is January 2023 through December 2023, I want to see how the MRR compares from July 2023 to July 2022 (we will always compare to the same month of the previous year). How can I do that?**

Unfortunately, I cannot provide any data samples as this data is confidential but I am happy to go into more detail from a high level if needed!

I've started with placing my raw data in PBI and creating a calendar table that autogenerates and provides a monthly view (so one row for every month of the year from January 2019-December 2023). But, I'm stuck at this point on how to move forward.

Comment: Figured I'd give a generic example that may help:

Customer X's initial contract was January 1, 2022 through December 31, 2022. Their TCV was $12,000, so their MRR is $1,000 in 2022. When they renewed their contract in 2023, we doubled their contract (super unlikely but makes for easy math). So, for January 1, 2023 through December 31, 2023, their TCV is now $24,000 so their MRR is $2,000 in 2023.

If I want to look at Customer X's growth and compare specifically October 2023 against October 2022, I should be able to tell we upsold them and the difference is $1,000 MRR.

Comment: I would convert your source to have monthly records. Not sure how to do this with power BI, but if you can use sql, you can create a recursive query based on start and end date and TC/NumberOfMonths(datediff function usually).

Comment: Thanks @KeithL. I'll look into that!

Comment: Can you  update your question and update this part "Bottom Line: If a contract is January 2023 through December 2023, I want to see how the MRR compares from July 2023 to July 2022. How can I do that?" as it is confusing and maybe has a typo. And are you wanting to compare month to any month or to same month of previous year?

Comment: It's the month to the same month of the previous year. I'll update! @SamNseir

Comment: I found this response on the Microsoft Community that will ultimately get me where I need to go: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/spread-revenue-over-future-months/td-p/607050 The response from v-jiascu-msft was the answer I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CALCULATE() and then shift the evaluation context of the measure back a year...

```
PY MRR =   CALCULATE( [MRR], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DimDate) )
```

and PowerBI will take care of the date shifting. Then you can calculate the delta by doing something like this:

```
[MRR] - [PY MRR]

delta % = DIVIDE ([MRR] - [PY MRR], [PY MRR])
```

Comment: Thanks @Pieter. I tried this but did not get any data in my PY MRR column. Here's what I did so maybe you can figure out where I went wrong:

PY MRR = CALCULATE( SUM('Raw Data'[MRR]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date Comparison'[First Day of Month]) )

The Date Comparison table is an autogenerated date table that just has month and year lines. Perhaps I need to use a different column?

Comment: You will need a Date column with continuous dates for it to work.

Comment: @SamNseir That needs to come from my date table (called 'Date Comparison')? If so, that's what I have already.

Comment: I'm also not clear how this will actually split out the MRR over each month within the term. I have a feeling this solution will just give me the MRR for the first month of the term, but not spread it out over the remaining months. For example, if the contract is 1/1/2020 - 12/31/2020, I'll see MRR for January 2020 but nothing for February, March, etc.

Comment: It will work so long as you have the month in a visual. For each month in the visual, it will do the `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` calculation.

Comment: Consider uploading a sample PBIX and updating your question with a link. I understand you have confidential data, but you can still create a mock-up pbix with dummy data, just enough to demonstrate the issue or need.